# matplotlib figure does not open since update

Tags: matplotlib, ipython, anaconda

After an update to ipython 5.0.0 figures do not open in interactive mode anymore. At least for me. They do open in a normal python shell though.

So **this works**, i.e. a window with a plot opens:

```
me@box:~$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.ion()
>>> plt.plot([1,2,3])
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x7fc5fdbbae48>]
```

While this **does not work**:

```
me@box:~$ ipython
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 2.4.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:53:06) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
In [2]: plt.ion()
In [3]: plt.plot([1,2,3])
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fab81f31da0>]
```

A window *does* open, when I hit Ctrl+D to leave ipython or when I type `plt.pause(0.1)`.

---

I should add, that it does work when I use `ipython --pylab`.
So the question is: What important things does `ipython --pylab` do apart from:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ion()
```

Comment: IIRC, `ipython --pylab` should give you a message about being deprecated. Instead, use the `%matplotlib` magic or the `--matplotlib` command line argument, see here: http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/reference.html#plotting-with-matplotlib